# How to install Afterstep on ubuntu?

Tags: x11

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I'd like to install Afterstep.
I'm quite new in Unix don't know how to compile.

Comment: This is an honest question.  I'd rather see him say "new to Unix/Linux" than a -1.  A piece of advice though.  Soak up as much as you can through `man pages`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to compile packages on Ubuntu, unless the package you need or want doesn't exist in a repository.  It just so happens that AfterStep is in one of those repositories.

Execute the Following to add the Universe Repository, and verify the defaults:

`sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty trusty-updates universe"`

Then issue an update:
`apt-get update`

Search for your desired package:
`apt-cache search afterstep`

which should return something like [The AfterStep Binary in Trusty](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/afterstep/2.2.12-2), which can then be installed with:
`sudo apt-get install afterstep`